# Qt (C++) Pass Variable from Dialog to main.cpp

Tags: c++, qt, variables, dialog

When i start my Program a Dialog-Window pops up and asks me to enter a name. Once i've entered my Name and press the Button it closes the Dialog and opens the main window.

My question is how i get the variable/ Name i just set in the Dialog into another class / my main.cpp

Main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtDebug>
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <sstream>
#include "mydialog.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    // Open Dialog
    MyDialog mDialog;
    mDialog.setModal(true);
    mDialog.exec();

    //Open Main Window
    GW2::MainWindow w;
    w.show();    
    return a.exec();
}
```

mydialog.cpp

```
#include "mydialog.h"
#include "ui_mydialog.h"
#include <QDebug>

using namespace std;


MyDialog::MyDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MyDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MyDialog::~MyDialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MyDialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString MYNAME = ui->lineEdit->text();
    close();
}
```

I can get MYNAME here that works after i press the Button but i need to pass the Variable...

mydialog.h

```
#ifndef MYDIALOG_H
#define MYDIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QString>


namespace Ui {

class MyDialog;
}

class MyDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MyDialog();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();


private:
    Ui::MyDialog *ui;
};

#endif // MYDIALOG_Hs
```

I tried using google and search function but didn'T find anything that worked on my project. Hope you can help me. Cheers

Comment: You can make your `my_name` variable a member of the class MyDialog. Not a bad solution at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in `MyDialog`:

```
QString MyDialog::getName()
{
    return ui->lineEdit->text();
}
```

Then do:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    // Open Dialog
    MyDialog mDialog;
    mDialog.setModal(true);
    mDialog.exec();

    // retrieve the name    
    QString name = mDialog.getName();

    //Open Main Window
    GW2::MainWindow w;
    w.show();    
    return a.exec();
}
```

Note that the dialog could be canceled. You should call `accept()` rather than `close()` from `on_pushButton_clicked()` and later test if the dialog was accepted or not:

```
if ( mDialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted )
{
    QString name = mDialog.getName();
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you that did the trick! Was overthinking this whole topic and made weird stuff but now it works! THanks.